# Is it legal to mirror a website if that causes a lot of traffic?

Tags: internet

There is a website that offers a lot of game patches. I wrote a program that downloads all of them. I want the files for my personal use only. I do not want to publish them on the internet.

I think it could be 1000GB of data causing a lot of traffic. So cost may arise for the server owners. I am planning to download everything within 3 months.

My internet connection is only 50MBit. So it won't disable the page when I am downloading. Also copyright should not be a problem.

My question is if the traffic I cause is a problem. Because traffic is never for free. I am from Germany.

So is it legal?

Comment: Does the website in question have a terms-of-use?

Comment: @jwh20 I don't want to say which site it is exactly. But I have looked into the terms-of-use and they are generic. They simply say nothing about how many files you may download.

Comment: I really doubt that there is any legal question here unless you are doing something that violates some law in your jurisdiction.  But that would probably have to involve some sort of intent to defraud or damage the service provider.